# navigate to page in user control (metro app win8)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, user-controls

I have add usercontrol and I want to navigate different pages in user control ,

I have tried a lot of method like below :

`var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                        frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.createNewsLetter));`

and 
`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.createNewsLetter));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello Ali what you can do is define a **Frame** type static varible in your **App.xaml.cs** and can navigate with respect to this frame like this..
there is a Frame type variable name **rootframe** in your App.xaml.cs in **OnLaunched** method convert this local variable to public static variable like this.

```
 public static Frame RootFrame ;
```

now in your **usercontrol** use this RootFrame as a reference to navigate like this..

```
 App.RootFrame.Navigate((typeof(MainPage)));
```

hope it will solve your problem..